# Firebase messaging and Google Play service anylatics duplicate analytic

Tags: android, google-analytics, duplicates

I tried to add Firebase messaging to use push notification and Google Play service analytics to tracking my app with google analytics. When I syns now build it is ok but when I run app it show error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.>com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1.class
```

I try to add Myapplication.class with

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

and add multiDexEnabled true in build, But it not work
Here is my build.gradle

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hoatv.videotrailer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    provided 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    compile files('libs/valuepotion.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile 'com.github.Commit451.YouTubeExtractor:youtubeextractor:2.1.0'
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How can I fix it? please help me! thanks alot!

Comment: Did you added analytics jar as well ?It's saying duplicate entry for analytics.Means you have added it more than once ..Try cleaning the project too..

Comment: Tks I will try it, Before I added LibAnylatic.jar but  after I deleted it it in dependencies. Hope it done :)